# How to set positive-definite function to be equal to the length of inputs?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, positive-definite

I want to prove or rebut the following: 
Given a full rank $n \times n$ matrix $\mathbf{M}$, the following equality is true:
$\mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{M} \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{v}^T \mathbf{v}, $ for all $ \mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, iff $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{I}$, where $\mathbf{I}$ is corresponding identity matrix. I know how to prove that elements on the diagonal of M are 1, but I cannot prove that elements outside of the diagonal are zero.

Comment: In fact, the statement is false.  A matrix $M$ will satisfy your equality if and only if $M + M^T = 2I$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes you are right, just put it is as an answer, so I could accept it. :) I will update the question so it says to prove or rebut .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, we will have $v^TMv = v^Tv$ for all $v \in \Bbb R^n$ if and only if $M + M^T = 2I$.  One non-symmetric, full-rank example would be
$$
M = \pmatrix{1&-1\\1&1}.
$$
While the off-diagonal entries are not necessarily zero, they do satisfy $a_{ij} = -a_{ji}$.